# Wordpress shortcode looping data

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create my first wordpress shortcode by scrapping data from a site and post it. However i have problem connecting the php loop with my html code and then return the html. I want to create a row every time the loop is executed and placing the opp1, opp2 and score in the table and then retun the html script

```
<table class="match-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
   <tr class="margin-tr">
        <td class="match-icon">Icon</td>
        <td class="match-home">Opp1</td>
        <td class="match-score">score</td>
        <td class="match-away">opp2</td>
        <td class="match-time">22:00</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

php:

```
function getGames() {

$html = str_get_html(getHTML($url,10));

    //$title = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '',$html->find("/[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/strong",0)->plaintext);
    //$manuf = $html->find("/[@id='main']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong",0)->plaintext;
$table = $html->find("/[@id='matches_list']/",0);

foreach($table->find("li") as $line){
    $game = $line->find("a/span/img",0)->title;
    if(  $game == "CS:GO" or $game == "Hearthstone" or $game == "Dota 2" or $game == "StarCraft II" or $game == "League of Legends"){

        $opp1 = $line->find("span.opp1",0)->plaintext;
        $opp2 = $line->find("span.opp2",0)->plaintext;
        $score = $line->find("span.score",0)->plaintext;


        }

    }

}

add_shortcode('getGames', 'getGames');
```

Comment: can you explain your current issue a bit more. What is your expected output from the loop you have written vs. what you are actually getting out of it?